# Are commissions paid to realtors for finding tenants for my rental property tax deductable as a rental expense?

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, tax-deduction

I used a realtor to find a tenant for my rental home. I paid her a commission of the amount equal to the first months rent. Is this what turbotax means by Commission Expenses "Commissions paid to salespeople"? Does "salespeople" include this realtor?

In other words, Can I deduct the commission amount that I paid this realtor for finding me a tenant?

Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this counts as a deductible expense. If their help resulted in a rental agreement that is very easy to document, just keep the bill, a copy of the check, and the rental agreement.

If the search was unsuccessful, still keep the bill and a copy of the check, plus more documentation to show that a service was actually performed. Note if they ran ads, showed the unit... This is just in case you get audited.